# Review triage test question has wrong disposition

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just got this answer - and said it was ok - but failed the audit which claimed it was `spam or nonsense and should be considered Unsalvageable`.  It's not: it's *very* wordy, and could have been written a *lot* better but it is actually a proper answer.  I couldn't find any feedback button on the test itself, so I'm offering it up here.  I see there's a tag here `disputed-review-audits` so presumably this is the proper feedback mechanism for invalid audit questions (or is that am I wrong here and this is spam)?

[Review|Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12309674)

```
Association:

It represents a relationship between two or more objects where all objects
have their own lifecycle and there is no owner. The name of an association
specifies the nature of relationship between objects. This is represented 
by a solid line.

Let’s take an example of relationship between Teacher and Student. Multiple
students can associate with a single teacher and a single student can 
associate with multiple teachers. But there is no ownership between the 
objects and both have their own lifecycle. Both can be created and deleted
independently.

Aggregation:

It is a specialized form of Association where all object have their own
lifecycle but there is ownership. This represents “whole-part or a-part-of”
relationship. This is represented by a hollow diamond followed by a line.

Let’s take an example of relationship between Department and Teacher. A
Teacher may belongs to multiple departments. Hence Teacher is a part of 
multiple departments. But if we delete a Department, Teacher Object will
not destroy.

... and much much more  in this vein ...
```

Comment: Triage isn't for answers...

Comment: yeah ... I guess I got confused between the triage queue and the late answer queue I had been at before ... sorry!

Answer (score 6):

You wrote:

> I just got this answer

That thing you linked to *really* looks like a question to me.

I mean, except for the bit where it doesn't ask any questions and mostly just advertises someone's blog.

As a rule of thumb, you should never get any answers in Triage. The entire purpose of that particular review queue is to categorize *questions*. If you encounter something that doesn't look like a question, "Looks OK" is very much the wrong choice.

Comment: huh - I just assumed it was an answer to a relevant question.  As a question I can see why you say it "mostly just advertises ...".